# How to calc distance between two postcodes without API - PHP preferred

Tags: php, postal-code

I've been making search functionality that takes in two fields, Start Postcode and End Postcode. The search is supposed to query the database and collect any records that fall into the radius for both postcodes. I can retrieve the records but after, I need to get the distance between the postcodes. I know how to use the GMaps API to do this but I need to do it locally with PHP for performance reasons (Looping over multiple records etc). It would be very bad for performance to do this with an API. Any suggestions?

Just to be clear: I need a code solution to calculate distance between two postcodes without API use. Is this possible and if so how?

PHP is preferred but even just the logical idea represented in any language is okay for me.

Comment: It's possible if you have the location data, I guess, latitude and longitude of every postcode, and the means to keep that up to date when the list changes.

Comment: Right. That can be done performance wise as only one record is stored at a time so an API request can be done to get the Lat/lng at that point. So you're suggesting to calc the distance I need the Lat/Lng? How do I return the difference in miles? Or KM if it helps? @ADyson

Comment: Well a postcode by itself doesn't contain anything intrinsically which tells you its exact location mathematically, does it? It's just a coding system for sorting mail. How would you propose to make any kind of calculation based on a postcode alone? It's systematic, but not in a way which allows you to make a judgement about the location of one postcode area relative to another.

Comment: Ohh yes of course, you're absolutly right. Got brain fuzz from all the hours i've been thinking about this then. So another question would be how to the lat lng from a postcode without api? I guess there isn't a way without an API. Perhaps a pre made Database of postcodes with their lat lngs?

Comment: Yes you need some sort of lookup, nothing about the postcode gives this away on its own. And then you need to keep the list up to date periodically because this data is not static (e.g. when new houses are built, or the postal service decides to change things around). If you're talking about the UK you can certainly buy regular updates from Royal Mail, or they may even have got round to giving it away for free, it's been a while since I worked with it.

Comment: Okay brilliant thanks very much. So say I used the Royal Mail DB (The clients paying for it), would it simply query the DB and match the entered postcode to a row in that database and collect the lat/lng from there? Does the RMDB even have lat/lng values do you know?

Comment: From memory I'm pretty sure it does, you can look at https://www.poweredbypaf.com/ for more info, also https://www.poweredbypaf.com/uk-addresses_address_postcode_look-up_software/ or https://www.poweredbypaf.com/using-our-address-data/use-the-data-yourself/ might be relevant

Answer (score 4):

If you have latitude and longtitude you can calculate the distance between two points without api just using this code:

```
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {

  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
  $dist = acos($dist);
  $dist = rad2deg($dist);
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  $unit = strtoupper($unit);

  if ($unit == "K") {
    return ($miles * 1.609344);
  } else if ($unit == "N") {
      return ($miles * 0.8684);
    } else {
        return $miles;
      }
}

echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "M") . " Miles<br>";
echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "K") . " Kilometers<br>";
echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "N") . " Nautical Miles<br>";
```

Comment: This code seems to be copied from elsewhere, probably [from here](http://www.geodatasource.com/developers/php), which is licensed under LGPL.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is very useful, tested and it works well. The only thing is I compared the results to a google matrix api call and your function returned 18 miles and google returned 22. Could you explain the inaccuracy so I understand the issues and limitations etc

Comment: Yeah it's not my code it's from: https://www.geodatasource.com/developers/php

But you don't have to implement it, google for it or write your own function. I just wanted to show you how the problem could be solved now its your turn.

The inaccuracy depends on how you measure the distance, I don't exactly know how google internally calculates the distance. The example above calculates the linear distance, no routes or something similar

Answer (score 1):

Store the Lat Lon when you save the record and then work it out from that. It does mean a call to Google Maps API on save though.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, we actually established this in the comments above. I had a bit of brain fuzz from thinking about this so much aha

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but it may help other people in future.
First, you can get Postcode -> Lat/long databases for free.
Here's a useful site which has plenty of geo mapping data like that:
https://www.freemaptools.com/download-uk-postcode-lat-lng.htm

Before you use such calculations though, you should think about what you want - straight-line 'As the crow flies' distances or driving distances. They are not the same!

To make a point, have a look at the Google Map: https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@51.4226247,-3.8874075,8.88z

The straight-line distance (calculated using Lat/Long) between, for example, Ilfracombe and Swansea is going to bear not relationship to the driving distance where you hav eto go up to the Severn bridge.

Calculating straight line distances - cheap and quick but inaccurate.

Calculating driving distances - accurate but very difficult to do yourself - an API, and its costs are necessary if you need this